# Unable to get all the transactions from PayPal using PayPal PHP SDK

Tags: laravel

I am trying to get all the transactions from Paypal using PayPal PHP SDK but facing header error 10002. I am using the Laravel framework to get these transactions.

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue too. I wrote a WP Plugin that used to work but then stopped sometime earlier this year.

Comment: Okay let's see if anyone give the best answer that will help to handle this issue :)